# Create swipe controlled simple flipbook style animation in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am a beginner in Obj C development, though quite experienced (over 10 years) with other ECMAscript based languages and OOP development.

I want to build a simple flipbook style animation, controlled through swiping motion. I'm sure extremely simple for any advanced ObjC coders.

Can anyone with extensive ObjC-CocoaTouch experience give me some higher level recommendations?
ie, 
1 -general application design, should I start with a simple view based application, or navigation based or?
2 -should I use 3rd party animation frameworks such as Cocos2D, or stick with built in classes and methods?
3 -if using built in methods, classes, what is the recommended way of achieving a animation, that will be controlled via swipe and touch gestures?
4 -I want to eventually have multiple 'flipbooks' that I can 'instantly' swap with one another, ie to give the net effect of an object changing color, etc, but not sure how to approach this from a memory management point of view, related to #1 above

Except for point 3 above, I'm not expecting any actual code examples. Just general guidelines to follow and perhaps, what are some next steps I should take in my goal as an ObjC code samurai.

Answer (score 0):

While I am no expert I can think of a few things you could pursue to get the effect you want.  Sounds like you want have a somewhat immersive experience for users.  Cocos2D would definitely  fit that bill.  Me and my team at [Get Set Games](http://www.getsetgames.com) have been using it for the past year and have not been dissapointed with it.  We haven't done the flipbook effect you speak of but quite possibly someone in the Cocos2D forums has implemented are at least attempted this.  Forums are [accessible here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).

Having said that I think starting with the iPhone SDK UIKit framework and basic examples that come with it are great.  There is a great array of samples on scrolling, swiping, etc.  If you want to hook in Cocos2D or other frameworks later that's definitely an option.

Comment: Thanks. Will probably get my head wrapped around UIImageView first, then have a look at Cocos2D